# Letsencrypt issues with PHP script (cpvlab)

Tags: php, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, easy-engine

So, I have a problem, and this may or may not be the place to ask this question, but I'm doing it anyway - since I've tried everything and nothing works …

Here goes:

I have a tracking script installed on a digital ocean server … it’s called CPVlab. It enables me to track clicks and gives me statistics on the click. What it does is catch info on a user and their behavior and it can rotate landing pages for split testing those landing pages. This is all done through internal redirects on the domain the script is installed on.

Let’s say it’s installed on : tracker.com

Another feature of the script is : I can enter an A record in the DNS I use and call it someothername.com and point it to the IP adres of the tracker.com.

This way, one can use different domains (tracking domains) in order to not have the main installation domain visible. This helps with customizing the look of different marketing campaigns (you don’t want them all to look like : tracker.com/? querystuff)…

So here’s the problem : It all used to work fine without https:// … But after installing letsencrypt (through an easyengine command for bothe tracker.com as well as tracking domains) the explained feature doesn’t work anymore.

When using **http://**someothername.com as an A record pointing to tracker.com, the server shows me a 404 not found status. And when I use a **https://**someothername.com as an A record pointing to the script, it tells me the connection is not secure. This while both domains have https certificates and they work if I put them in the browser direct. (it will show https).

However when I don’t use this tracking domain feature and just use the plain https://tracker.com domain, it works perfectly.

Maybe this question is a bit far out, but does anyone have an idea if this is related to letsencrypt ? I added the certificates through EE a few months ago, and I know EE uses certbot. However I am thinking that this problem may have something to do with letsencrypt not supporting wildcards at the time of install. Maybe this tracking script is designed in some way that the main domain uses the tracking domains as some sort of sub domain ?

Anyone have an idea about this ? I am definately STUCK here…

Thanks, Lex

Comment: _“This while both domains have https certificates”_ - well, you need to be a bit more precise at this point: Both domains are pointed to a web server originally, that knows it is supposed to serve that specific relevant certificate, when that domain is requested. Of course that isn’t the case any more, when you just point `someothername.com` to a different web server now ... _that_ web server would have to be configured to serve the appropriate certificate for this domain now. Of course it would also have to have the certificate file(s) available to begin with.

Comment: _After_ you pointed the DNS of your other domain to the server running tracker.com, that server could then create a LE certificate for `someothername.com`, but it would need to be implemented on their end.